# Java Web Start - NoSuchMethodError at startup

Tags: java, jar, classloader, java-web-start, nosuchmethoderror

I'm gettin some NoSuchMethodErrors in my Java Web Start application at the startup. This cause a fatal crash and force the app (and Java console) to exit.
At compile time there aren't errors, but when I run the application in Tomcat server it sometimes crash .

The application doesn't crash in every situation, in some PC Clients I get the same errors but the application lives anyway.

I found these errors using JMC (Java Mission Control) but I can't find a way to solve this problem. What can cause these errors?
I read that a jar \ library problem could be the reason (classloading problem) .

These are the jars I put in the .jnlp:

```
<jar href="jhome.jar" main="true" />
<jar href="jasperreports-5.1.0.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-logging-1.1.1.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-collections-2.1.1.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-digester-2.1.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-vfs2-2.0.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="jsch-0.1.51.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="poi-3.7-20101029.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-collections-3.2.1.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="commons-lang-2.5.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="ezmorph-1.0.6.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="json-lib-2.4-jdk15.jar" download="eager" />
<jar href="json-simple-1.1.1.jar" download="eager" />
```

Can you help me?

In every NoSuchMethodError the log shows a LinkageError -> IncompatibleClassChangeError (is it more specific?)

Here's a log. Every NoSuchMethodError I found have this log event

```
Error.<init>(String)            
LinkageError.<init>(String)         
IncompatibleClassChangeError.<init>(String)         
NoSuchMethodError.<init>(String)            
ObjectStreamClass.hasStaticInitializer(Class)           
ObjectStreamClass.computeDefaultSUID(Class)         
ObjectStreamClass.access$100(Class)         
ObjectStreamClass$1.run()           
ObjectStreamClass$1.run()           
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction)         
ObjectStreamClass.getSerialVersionUID()         
ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass, Class, ClassNotFoundException, ObjectStreamClass)         
ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(boolean)         
ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(boolean)            
ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(boolean)           
ObjectInputStream.readObject0(boolean)          
ObjectInputStream.readObject()          
ArrayList.readObject(ObjectInputStream)         
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[])          
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])           
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])           
Method.invoke(Object, Object[])         
ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Object, ObjectInputStream)           
ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Object, ObjectStreamClass)         
ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(boolean)           
ObjectInputStream.readObject0(boolean)          
ObjectInputStream.readObject()          
ObjectStreamingManager.unzip(InputStream)           
... (after ... there are some lines of methods written by me in the Project)
```

Comment: What method is it complaining about? Please edit your question to contain some more information

Comment: It looks like the app is picking up the wrong class file. Because i'm sure that the methods exist...

Comment: NoSuchMethodErrors could be the cause of the Java WS crash ?